# How to print numbers from 1 to 100 in flutter ListView?

Tags: listview, flutter

I'm a fresher in flutter & 
I'm Trying  to show Numbers from 1 to 100 in list view but don't know to set?

Comment: the easiest way is to use `ListView.builder` constructor

Comment: yup , i know &  even i have used it. but how to print these numbers ?

Comment: print where? you mean to show them on the `ListView`?

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
 new ListView.builder
      (
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
          return new Text(Index.toString());
        }
    )
```

for more detail refer this link : https://medium.com/@DakshHub/flutter-displaying-dynamic-contents-using-listview-builder-f2cedb1a19fb

Comment: When answering a "How to" question without asking the user about what did he/she tried, you're encouraging them to ignore researching old question and wasting other users' time.It also supports some new users' perception about the site as a "free coding service".

Comment: @MazinIbrahim **very** well said, is it your own words or is it some kind of official SO "template" that can be used for such answers?

Comment: @pskink my own word :), but I read many comments from reputable users revolving around these points. Some of these points are mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MazinIbrahim so could i "borrow" your words for such cases?

Comment: @pskink Anytime you want !

Comment: @MazinIbrahim ok thanx a lot then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
   var list=100;
   --------------
   body: new ListView(
          children: new List.generate(list, (int index){
        return new ListTile(title: new Text("List Number - $index"),
        );
      })
  ),
```